# Deleted the contents of /usr/share/X11/locale/compose.dir

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout

So I was working on making a custom keyboard layout and I needed to make a character (s¨, to be exact), long story...

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

But anyways I accidentally deleted and saved the contents of `/usr/share/X11/locale/compose.dir`.

Is there any way to recover the default contents of it? Or is it somewhere online where I can copy the contents?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Edit: thanks so much, @muru it worked!

Comment: (Same principle for anything in `/usr/share`)

Comment: @muru Yes! Thank you so much!